# TFLite evaluation: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (128,128,3) into shape (1,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflite

I'm trying to emulate the code from https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/quantization/training_example. More precisely, evaluating the TFLite model against the baseline model.

```
def evaluate_model(interpreter):
  input_index = interpreter.get_input_details()[0]["index"]
  output_index = interpreter.get_output_details()[0]["index"]

  # Run predictions on every image in the "test" dataset.
  prediction_digits = []
  for i, test_image in enumerate(test_images):
    if i % 1000 == 0:
      print('Evaluated on {n} results so far.'.format(n=i))
    # Pre-processing: add batch dimension and convert to float32 to match with
    # the model's input data format.
    test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0).astype(np.float32)
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_index, test_image)

    # Run inference.
    interpreter.invoke()

    # Post-processing: remove batch dimension and find the digit with highest
    # probability.
    output = interpreter.tensor(output_index)
    digit = np.argmax(output()[0])
    prediction_digits.append(digit)

  print('\n')
  # Compare prediction results with ground truth labels to calculate accuracy.
  prediction_digits = np.array(prediction_digits)
  accuracy = (prediction_digits == test_labels).mean()
  return accuracy
```

However, i get the following error:
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (128,128,3) into shape (1,)

I might add that images are in an dataframe iterator.

How can i fix this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which line number?

Comment: test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0).astype(np.float32)